# Life-time of obect urls with web-workers

Tags: javascript, blob, web-worker

Say we start a Worker and it creates an object URL from a blob:

```
//running in page window
var worker = new Worker(workerScriptUrl);


//running in worker
var u = rootScope.URL || rootScope.webkitURL;
var objUrl = u.createObjectURL(blob);
```

...now (because we're lazy) we don't ever call:

```
u.revokeObjectURL(objUrl);
```

and instead in the code that started the worker, we simply call:

```
worker.terminate();
```

Will this kill the object url, or will it remain for the duration of the original page window?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in the absence of an answer, I decided to test this myself:

```
var u = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var f='('+

function(rootScope){
    var u = rootScope.URL || rootScope.webkitURL;
    var blob=new Blob([ "hello world!" ], { type: 'text/plain' } );
    var blobURL = u.createObjectURL( blob) ;
    rootScope.postMessage(blobURL);
}.toString()+

')(this)';
console.log(f);
// Build a worker from an anonymous function body
var blobURL = u.createObjectURL( new Blob([ f ], 
                                          { type: 'application/javascript' } ) );

var worker = new Worker( blobURL );
worker.onmessage=function(e){
    worker.terminate();
    setTimeout(function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', e.data, false);
        xhr.send(null);
        console.log( xhr.responseText );    //prints "hello world!" 
    },5000);
};

// Won't be needing this anymore
u.revokeObjectURL( blobURL );
```

As can be seen, even five seconds after we terminate the web-worker, we can still read the object URL that it created.